# Can there be two span tags with one span close tag

Tags: xhtml

I am reading the code written by somebody. I need to make modifications but I see that they have used

```
       <span class="TextUnderlined">
        <span class="colorText">
             </span>
```

Is this possible? I thougth each span tag needs to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

**Each span tag should have its own closing tag.**

The fact that a browser might handle this error doesn't make it OK.

Answer (score 0):

According to HTML specifications all tags must have their closing tag. 
So the answer is no.

Having said that nobody is stopping you from doing it but this will cause issues with most of the browsers.

Why do you need one closing span tag for 2 spans?